# android: "flushing toilet" vortex path animation

Tags: android, animation, path

I am learning how to make animation, is there a way to mimic a motion path such that an icon can follow a "flushing toilet" vortex path, from outside circle to inner circle and then to center?

Need to find out the vortex equation?

or an icon to follow circle motion, and with the radius keep decreasing?

is there a simple way just to use those translate.xml? Many thanks!